# Windows 8.1 No picture password option, despite enabling in policies

Tags: windows, active-directory, login

I want to enable picture logon to domain-joined Windows 8.1. However in Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options, there is no option for that, but unhelpful "Some settings are managed by your system administrator".

Setting "Turn off picture password sign-in" to Disabled didn't help (I've rebooted and verified gpresult which looks ok).

Any suggestions why it would be disabled, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to enable it via RDP. Real shame that is not mentioned nowhere in UI or documentation!

We use VMs extensively and typically RDP to them it never occurred to me that could be the problem...

Comment: I have only just seen this update: you never originally mentioned you were trying to use it over RDP!

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Interactive logon: Do not display last user name" in your AD GPO as well.

Comment: Tried setting it on AD, then machine level, ran gpupdate and even rebooted machine. Still no luck.

Comment: Officially tapped out on ideas, then. I don't use picture passwords (or indeed any 8.x in AD yet) and so was only suggesting what I could immediately see as the remaining obstacle. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for trying though. I've tried on domain-joined and un-joined and no luck :(